# Get all xml attributes in key=value notation

Tags: xml, xmlstarlet

Suppose I have:

```
$ cat file
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<msg date='2020-03-21' time='2021-04-27T11:33:27Z' 
            type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='localhost'
            host_addr='127.0.0.1' pid='6322'>
    <txt>service_update * orclcdb = 0</txt>
</msg>
```

I would like to get all the attributes under `//msg` as `key=value` pairs.

With `ruby` I could do:

```
ruby -r nokogiri -e '
doc=Nokogiri::XML($<.read)
doc.xpath("//msg/@*").each{ |e| puts "#{e.name}=#{e.value}" }
' file
```

And get:

```
date=2020-03-21
time=2021-04-27T11:33:27Z
type=UNKNOWN
level=16
host_id=localhost
host_addr=127.0.0.1
pid=6322
```

If I want all the elements and attributes, I can do:

```
ruby -r nokogiri -e '
doc=Nokogiri::XML($<.read)
doc.xpath("//msg/@* | //msg/*").each{ |e| 
    puts "#{e.name}=#{e.content}"}
' file 

date=2020-03-21
time=2021-04-27T11:33:27Z
type=UNKNOWN
level=16
host_id=localhost
host_addr=127.0.0.1
pid=6322
txt=service_update * orclcdb = 0
```

I am trying to replicate this in `xmlstarlet`

I have tried:

```
xmlstarlet sel -T -t -m "//msg/*" -v "concat(name(),'=',text())" -n  file
```

But that works only for tags, not attributes.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `text()` that only refers to the content of a text node and is meaningless to an attribute.

You need to use the `.` which is the [context item](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#dt-context-item) (or [context item expression](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#id-context-item-expression)) for either a node, attribute, or atomic value.

```
xmlstarlet sel -T -t -m "//msg/@*" -v "concat(name(),'=',.)" -n file 
date=2020-03-21
time=2021-04-27T11:33:27Z
type=UNKNOWN
level=16
host_id=localhost
host_addr=127.0.0.1
pid=6322
```

Or if you want both nodes and attributes:

```
xmlstarlet sel -T -t -m "//msg/@* | //msg/*" -v "concat(name(),'=',.)" -n file 
date=2020-03-21
time=2021-04-27T11:33:27Z
type=UNKNOWN
level=16
host_id=localhost
host_addr=127.0.0.1
pid=6322
txt=service_update * orclcdb = 0
```

Comment: Well done -- useful to have recorded.  Thanks for posting.

Comment: Thanks! I searched for this for hours!